# Convert JSON to string and write to a file

Tags: mule, dataweave

How can i convert a JSON object to String and write to a file?
The output type in data weave is application/java

[image]

Comment: Why do you need Object to Json Transformer ? Transform Message component can directly result the output in JSON. Pls share your flow to let us know what you tried.

Comment: I am inserting the payload data to DB after writing to File. In the insert statement, i am referring to each element of the payload in this format #[payload.?element_1]. To be able to do this, i have the output format as application/java. I want to write the output of data weave in a file. So i am converting the java object to json and writing to file. However its writing some gibberish to file.

Answer (score 1):

If the output in DataWeave is set to application/json just sending the payload to a file transport should write the payload to the file.

Example:

```
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp" outputPattern="jsonoutput"   responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```

Comment: What is the input and Mule version?

Answer (score -1):

you can convert to a string by directly using an object to a string component. then there no need of object to JSON component in your flow.